# Jumpy scroll after scroll-animation with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a problem with the scrolling animation. Jumpy scroll occurs when the page is scrolled after scroll-animation. I suspected the scroll-event repeats itself, but I'm not sure. Can you help me with it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var offset;
var anchor = $("#navigation").offset().top;  
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
offset = $(window).scrollTop();

if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
    //mouse scroll down
    console.log('Down: ' + offset + " " + anchor);

    if (offset >= anchor) {
        // if anchor has been scrolled, user can scroll further
        // the problem ocuurs in this block
        return true;
    } else {
        // animate to anchor( nav menu)
        $("body, html").animate({
            scrollTop: anchor + 1
        }, 200);
        $("#navigation").addClass("nav-fixed");
        return false;
    }
} else {
    //mouse scroll up
    if (offset < anchor) {
        $("#navigation").removeClass("nav-fixed");
        return true;
    }
}});
```

});

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0noms3cs/

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is simple.  The scroll event fires over and over again.  Your line of thinking behind the cause of this issue is correct, you have a large number of `animate` events that get stacked up which causes this weird behavior.

<s>You can resolve this issue by adding a boolean variable (such as `scrollInitialized`) that starts out as `false` and gets flipped to `true` once the scroll event has fired once.</s>

Here's the altered JS code.  Note:  I only added the `scrollInitialized` variable and a check for it in the if statement.

**Edit**: I also removed the inner `if-else` case since it was not necessary using this design.

**EDIT 2**:  I originally misunderstood what you wanted to do.  What you need to do was add a `scrollLock` variable that would only be set to `true` for the duration of your animation.  After thinking about this, I implemented it for you.  Here is the Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/04gaaapo/1/

Here is the new JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var scrollLock = false;
    var offset;
    var anchor = $("#navigation").offset().top;

    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        offset = $(window).scrollTop();

        // if scroll is NOT locked and we are above the anchor
        if (scrollLock === false && offset < anchor) {
            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                // scrolling down
                scrollLock = true;

                // animate to anchor( nav menu)
                $("body, html").animate({
                    scrollTop: anchor + 1
                }, 200);

                // unlock in 250ms
                setTimeout(toggleLock, 250);

                // add nav class
                $("#navigation").addClass("nav-fixed");

            } else if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
                // scrolling up
                scrollLock = true;

                // animate to top of page
                $("body, html").animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 200);

                // unlock in 250ms
                setTimeout(toggleLock, 250);

                // remove nav class
                $("#navigation").removeClass("nav-fixed");

            }
        }

    });

    function toggleLock() {
        scrollLock = !scrollLock;
    };

});
```

Comment: Thanx Christian, I had the idea too, but it worked just once.

Comment: I'm not sure what your expected behavior is then.  Can you go into more detail?  I thought having it fire once was the point.

Comment: Yes, gladly. The yellow block (header) should be always scrolled (with animation). If I scroll down, it should be scrolled down to anchor (nav). If scroll up - should be scrolled to page top.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include the functionality you wanted.  It took me a while to iron out the kinks but I hope it does what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Christian. Your solution worked for me perfectly.